Schematic Review Request: Lithium-ion Battery Power Supply
Hobbyist here again, packing another schematic to roast.
This is the second iteration of a Power Supply I'm trying to retrofit into a gas BBQ. For context, this is/was the first iteration:

no battery charging and protection circuitry
PMOS Q1 directly driven by MCU (now Q7 driven via NMOS Q8)
no attempt to handle transient voltages

I home-built a PCB for the 1st revision, and it works very well for the first try, except for those transients: The 5V supply is used to drive the BBQ ignition coil, pushing the button does something™ that resets the MCU and I can't even measure it (My cheap scope resets as well ).
Thus I deduct there's got to be some rather nasty voltage spikes when the igniter is turned on, which I hope to solve with this new design iteration. Before I go through another round of PCB design and manufacturing, I'd love some feedback.

Thanks for taking the time to review my stuff! Let me guide your attention slightly, though:

I've never yet wired the circuits for USB-C, LiIon charging and BMS myself yet, just used some ready-made modules - there could very much be some blunders there!
I'm intermediate at best when it comes to MOS circuits, so please tell me if my construction around Q5+Q6 (and Q7+Q8) makes sense!
I've never had to deal with transients like this before; never used a TVS diode yet - please rate this first attempt!

Finally, relevant datasheet links:

PMOS AO3401A: https://www.aosmd.com/sites/default/files/res/datasheets/AO3401A.pdf
NMOS 2302V: https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_2410010230_HL-2302V_C7431443.pdf
my TP4056 variant: https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_2409241408_UMW-Youtai-Semiconductor-Co---Ltd--TP4056_C725790.pdf
my DW01A variant: https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_2201121330_YONGYUTAI-DW01A_C2927799.pdf
dual NMOS BR8205: https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_1810311521_Foshan-Blue-Rocket-Elec-BR8205_C305455.pdf
ESD protection diode ES05S2HB23: https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_2408021729_GOODWORK-ES05S2HB23_C5137782.pdf


Just curious about why the net names to the left of J3 on the schematic have been "pixelated".

Normally I wouldn't be so nosy, but I do have to agree with Chester. If this is a "hobbyist" schematic, you have no good reason to pixelate anything – you've got no secrets to protect, so why go through that effort?

I'm just cautious, I took the original supply pack apart and used the same signal names for my retrofit. I don't want to risk trouble for publicly posting anything that might be considered IP by the original manufacturer.
